# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.models.feature_extraction'

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torch, feature-extraction

I want to extract features in ResNet101, however, I have trouble importing torchvision.models.feature_extraction.

Here is my code:

```
from torchvision import models    
from torchvision.models.feature_extractor import create_feature_extractor

res101 = models.resnet101(pretrained=True)

extractor = create_feature_extractor(
    res101,
    return_nodes=[
        "conv1", 
        "maxpool", 
        "layer1",
        "layer2",
        "layer3",
        "layer4",
    ]
)

features = extractor(inputs)
```

And here is the error

```
from torchvision.models.feature_extractor import create_feature_extractor
Traceback (most recent call last):

Input In [11] in <cell line: 1>
from torchvision.models.feature_extractor import create_feature_extractor

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.models.feature_extractor'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to use something like:

```
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor
```

See the `extraction` vs `extractor`

[Check this module](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/feature_extraction.html)

Comment: No matter whether I use extraction or extractor, the error is still happening. The error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.models.feature_extraction'" or "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.models.feature_extractor'".

Comment: Do you have `torchvision` installed in the first place? Try importing `import torchvision`. If no, then `pip install torchvision`

Comment: Yes, `import torchvision` and `import torchvision.model` are ok in the code.

Comment: Can you check your version of `torch` and `torchvision` and update to the new one?  Maybe you're using an old version when the module was unavailable.

Comment: My torch version is `1.9.1+cu111`, and torchvision version is `0.10.1+cu111`. Their versions seem not too old?

Comment: Maybe you got the package broken. One fix can be setting a new  `conda` or `virtualenv` for this task only and installing from scratch. This happens sometimes when you have ambiguous, unreachable, unregistered paths to the installed repo (just few of the many reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I installed PyTorch using `conda` and it works fine in Jupyter notebooks. But it does not work in terminal.

Turns out the `pip` listed `torchvision` version was `0.82`.

Solved by updating `torchvision` using `pip`.

Maybe some packages installed the old version for me. Hope my experience helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall torch, torchvision, and torchaudio. Then install the packages from preview(Nightly) from the following link https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

```
> pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio

> pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu117 --no-cache-dir
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but just had this problem recently and wanted to document what helped me fix it.

I looked up into my `torchvision/models` folder and saw that `feature_extraction.py` module was indeed there, but there was no mention of it.

So I modified `torchvision/models/__init__.py` to include it.

Here's a step by step:

1. Get torchvision path: `pip show torchvision` and look for Location. (in my case was `/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-YDPcP1OP-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages`)
2. cd into models inside torchvision path: `cd /your-path/torchvision/models`
3. Edit __ init__.py: `nano __init__.py`

   and add the following line `from . feature_extraction import *`

Done!

And just like that I could use feature_extraction module

```
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import get_graph_node_names
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor
```